# No DNS inside lxc container

Tags: networking, dns, lxc

I have an LXC debian container which run on my archlinux host. I tried to setup a bridge (lxc-bridge-nat) using wlan0 but **i can't ping the outside world from my container** except if i ping using the ip instead of the domain name.

I can ping the container from the host and the host from the container.

Here some informations:

**Host: ip addr**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:be:d9:70:bd:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:85:08:b4:5c:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.42.121/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::c685:8ff:feb4:5ce9/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: lxc-bridge-nat: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether fe:b3:b7:a2:e1:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.50.1/24 brd 192.168.50.255 scope global lxc-bridge-nat
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b0c8:d2ff:fe73:aa50/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**host: ip route**

```
default via 192.168.42.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
192.168.42.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.42.121  metric 9 
192.168.50.0/24 dev lxc-bridge-nat  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.50.1
```

**Container: ip addr**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:ff:aa:00:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.50.2/24 brd 192.168.50.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2ff:aaff:fe00:1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Container: ip route**

```
default via 192.168.50.1 dev eth0 
192.168.50.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.50.2
```

**Container: /etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 212.27.40.240
nameserver 212.27.40.241
```

Comment: Are you able to use nslookup to connect to either of those nameservers? If they're not available you won't have any DNS capability - try using alternatives, e.g. Google's.

Comment: Ok, it was the nameserver. I did ping them but not tested with nslookup. You might want to put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hostnames not resolving points immediately to the DNS servers, and posting the content of `resolv.conf` was useful here; they were the only part of this setup outside of your immediate control.

As you've found, simply pinging a remote server doesn't always help - running `nslookup` against them showed that they were the problem. *(As a counterpoint, due to the way `ping` itself works a lack of response from a ping doesn't mean the server is down - pings are trivial to block at firewall level.)*

To work around to your DNS issue, you can make use of other DNS servers, such as those [hosted by Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/). Simply alter your `resolv.conf` to:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: This didn't do it for me. I added `8.8.8.8` in the container's `/etc/network/interfaces` and in its `/etc/resolv.conf`, and I can certainly ping `8.8.8.8` from inside the container, but still no DNS. Since I can't `apt-get` without DNS, I can't even test `nslookup`.

Comment: @JonathanY. Did you restart networking and/or run `ifconfig`, just to confirm that the new DNS servers were now being used?

Comment: I did restart networking, and rebooted for good measure. However, although I've been trying to glean something regarding DNS out of `ifconfig`'s output, I'm not sure how to do it. [Other options](http://askubuntu.com/q/152593/142526) aren't viable (e.g., I can't install `nmcli` without DNS).

Comment: @JonathanY. My mistake, I thought it did (`ipconfig` on Windows does). Ok ... how about hard-coding the IP addresses of the servers `apt-get` uses into `/etc/hosts`, and short-cutting DNS entirely?

Comment: No problem. You might want to post it as a new question (askubuntu's probably more appropriate than here), as you're more likely to get a faster resolution.

Comment: Or ServerFault, I guess, since LXC isn't really Ubuntu-specific (and I got a feeling I'm only running into issues because I'm on Ubuntu Server). Okay then, that's what I'll do (I'll replace this with a link for future googlers).

Answer (score 1):

Adding 8.8.8.8 in /etc/network/interfaces is not a good idea. You should leave the interfaces file unchanged (restore the old settings) and modify only /etc/resolv.conf file.

You have set the container IP to the same IP of one of the Google's DNS servers.

Sure, the ping will work, but when you try to resolve a DNS hostname your container will contact itself and generate an error.